# Custom NLog AspNetLayoutRenderersBase not working on .NET Framework ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nlog

**Background:**

I'm building logging class library backed by NLog. The idea is to use this class library in our application to meet our logging needs. As part of this library, we wrote custom AspNetLayoutRenderers inherited from `AspNetLayoutRenderersBase`. The class library is targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 6. We have some applications based on .NET Framework and some are targeting .NET 6. The class library is using `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` package.

Issue Description:
The custom AspNetLayoutRenderers are perfectly working in .NET 6 web apps, however they are not working on full framework (.NET Framework 4.7.2). The NLog built in ASPNET layout renderers are also not working.

After enabling NLog internal log, we found below entry.

`No available HttpContext, because outside valid request context. Logger: Logging.SampleApp.NetFramework.Controllers.HomeController`

**Troubleshooting Performed:**

Registered `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` in `NLog.config` and also our assembly where we have custom aspnet layout renderers.

```xml
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
      <add assembly="Logging.Core" />
    </extensions>
```

The HomeController action is like below. I'm not using any async on controller actions and not starting any child tasks. Just simple action method.

```cs
    public ActionResult About()
    {
     try
     {
       throw new Exception("Test Exception");
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
      _logger.Error(ex, "Test Exception");
      return View();
     }
    }
```

In the Owin start up class, I configured the NLog.

```cs
    public IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
    {
      return services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => 
      {
           loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
           loggingBuilder.AddNLogWeb("NLog.config");
      });
    }
```

**Question**

Does same custom AspNetLayout renderers will work both for .NET 6 and .NET Framework 4.7.2 or we will need to implement separate custom layout renderers targetting different frameworks?

I can place NLog.config but not needed as the rest of the LogEvent properties are being logged. Only issue with NLog built in ASPNET layoutrenderer and my custom AspNetLayout renderers?

Basically I'm having trouble in understanding how the `HttpContextAccessor` abstraction works with both the frameworks?

Thanks!

Comment: `No available HttpContext, because outside valid request context` means that it cannot find the active HttpContext from the current HttpRequest. When using `NLog.Web.AspNetCore` then it means one is always build ASP.NET Core application, where the HttpContext-accessor is coming from `IServiceProvider` by calling `UseNLog()` / `AddNLogWeb()` / `RegisterNLogWeb()` where from it resolves `IHttpContextAccessor`

Comment: Notice `NLog.Web`-nuget-package is for classic ASP.NET MVC application for .NET Framework. And `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`-nuget-package is for ASP.NET Core applications (.NET Core + .NET Framework)

Comment: @RolfKristensen - Thanks a lot for the response. That's the reason, I have used NLog.Web.AspNetCore as it has support both for .NET Framework and .NET Core. BTW, even I tried with NLog.Web and no luck. I understand from the error that it cannot find the active HttpContext from the current MVC action request, but wondering if the current built in NLog AspNetLayout renderers work with both the frameworks. If yes, how can I make my custom AspNetLayout renderers work with both the frameworks.

Comment: Just like there is `NLog.Web` and `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`, then I guess you must split into 2 packages. `Logging.Core` and `Logging.Legacy` with their individual dependencies.

Comment: @RolfKristensen - Thanks for the response. I got biased with the Nuget frameworks support for NLog.Web.AspNetCore. I thought it will work out of the box on both the framework with just NLog.Web.AspNetCore.package, however that is not true. We will need to separate the Layout renderers into different packages with their dependencies.  BTW, once again, thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes one can build ASP.NET Core v2 applications on the NET Framework-platform. This exotic scenario is also supported by `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`, which might cause some confusion, as one usual think NET Framework only means System.Web.